# How do you go about making a sessionAttribute in Alexa Skills?

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm learning node with Alexa skills and was wondering how you go about actually creating a new session attribute.

I've tried looking up on [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) and youtube walkthroughs on how to do so... and I understand how to get and modify them but I'm stuck as to actually initializing them.
Any help would be appreciated.
(new to node by the way sorry if this seems easy.)

here is how I made the code for getting and setting the attributes, just want to go about making them though:

```
const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    const response = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    attributes.state = states.QUIZ;
    attributes.counter = 0;
    attributes.quizScore = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can check if your session is a new session using *Alexa.isNewSession*. If the session is new, you can go about initializing the attributes

```
if(Alexa.isNewSession(handlerInput.requestEnvelope)){
    const sessionAtts = {};
    // set your attributes here
    handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAtts);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the session attributes you need to make use of the setSessionAttributes method available on AttributesManager. Check out the documentation here: [Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html)

Code snippet:

```
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);
```

Comment: oh okay thanks that makes sense, how do you initalize them though? i.e. making an attribute called state that has a type called QUIZ? Thanks for the help again

Comment: yes, you are on the right track. In the code snippet you shared, you need to add the above line (setSessionAttributes) passing in your object (attributes)

Comment: When I put this into the code it states that the attributes are now unreachable. I'll check the link out though, thanks again